# When writing mySQL code, what's a better practice?

Tags: mysql, ddl

I'm learning mySQL, still on basic stuff. 
My teacher has said that when writing, the best codes have first, all the tables; then, ALTER TABLE queries inserting keys to the tables. That way, we can properly name the keys. I know for sure he does that to foreign keys. He has taught this with primary keys examples as well; however, when providing files with answers for exercises he proposed, he typed the primary keys inside the tables, and later only altered the foreign keys.
How should I do it then? Always insert primary keys inside the tables, alter the foreign keys later? Or should I alter both primary and foreign keys? I'm currently trying to do he latter, and bumping into auto_increment issues for the primary keys.
Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rename a primary key, so it makes no sense to do it later in an `ALTER` statement.
You're running into issues with auto_increment, because an auto_increment column also has to be (part of) the primary key. So you can not specify an auto_increment column but not make it primary key at the same time.

The thing is, this question is actually obsolete, as you can name your foreign keys also when creating the table. Which is for me the way that is prefered. Everything done in one statement. It would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
id int auto_increment primary key,
bar int,
constraint my_fancy_fk_name foreign key (bar) references other_table(whatever_column)
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I'm still too early on the course and the teacher will still talk about this. One question: I haven't fully understand what you meant in "So you have the choice to specify auto_increment + primary key when you're creating the table or do it later for both, but not auto_increment when creating the table and adding primary key later in ALTER statement. " Can you please try to rephrase it? Sorry about it, english is not my first language...

Comment: Of course, rephrased it. It simply means, that you have to make an auto_increment column primary key at the same time. Either when creating the table, or you just specify the data type when creating the table and make it auto_increment and primary key (at the same time) in an `alter` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have to add this raises another question: I did try to do something like the alternative you mentioned. I created a table with an ID INT, and later altered it with alter table, and added primary key auto_increment(id); it turned it into primary key, but it did not implement the auto_increment. Is it because I have to choose either the table or the alter table to write the whole thing? Example: write in the table only "id", and then alter table INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT(ID)? I cannot set the INT inside the table and leave everything else in the alter table?

Comment: Here's an example how to do it with an `alter` statement (no other way, as you have to do it all in one step): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39a5bf/2/0  But may I ask why you waste so much energy on this topic? Just do everything in your create table statement and name your foreign keys properly and you're fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying! I pretty newbie, I just want to make sure I'm fully grasping the basis correctly, so I screw up less when more complicated stuff comes. I'm so sorry if it fells like I'm overdoing this, in my head this is like the four basic operations of math - if I don't get that, I will mess up everything else. Thank you again for your patience!